# How to add the label of item when pressed and delete it when again pressed with item separator(,)?

Tags: android

[Edited]
Something like this..
when pressed the item labels are added with comma if there is item more than two[and when pressed again deletes the item labels with comma 
this is what ive done so far
Note SeatP is a textView and seat_n is selected item label from the list

```
List<Seats> seatsList;
GridView myGrid;
MyGridAdapter adapter;
TextView seatlabel,pricelabel;
ImageView im;
String st,seat_n,seatp;
```

myGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

```
    seatlabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelSeat);
    pricelabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelPrice);
```

public void updateMessage(){

```
    adapter = new MyGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.seat_item,seatsList);
    myGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    myGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            st = seatsList.get(position).getStatus();
            seat_n = seatsList.get(position).getSeat_no();
            p = seatsList.get(position).getPrice();
            Log.d("price: ", p + "");

            //Log.d("status: ", seat_n + "");
            im = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.seat1);

            if (st.equalsIgnoreCase("available")) {

                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.seat);
                myStatus = true;
                seatsList.get(position).setStatus("select");
                Log.d("status 1: ",myStatus+"");
                if (seatp.length()>1){
                    seatp = seatp+"," + seat_n;
                }else {
                    seatp = seatp+ seat_n;
                }
                pr = pr+p;

                seatlabel.setText(seatp.trim());
                pricelabel.setText(Integer.toString(pr));

            }
            if(st.equalsIgnoreCase("select")) {
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seat: " + seatsList.get(position).getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.seat_avv);
                seatsList.get(position).setStatus("available");
                pr = pr-p;
                pricelabel.setText(Integer.toString(pr));
                seatp= seatlabel.getText().toString();
                //Log.d("seatlabel: ",ab);
                //seatp= seatp.replace(seat_n, "");
                if(seatp.length()>=5){
                    seatp= seatp.replace(","+seat_n, "");
                }else {
                    seatp= seatp.replace(seat_n+",", "");
                }
                Log.d("seatp Length: ",seatp.length()+"");
                /*if(seatp.length()>2){
                    seatp= seatp.replace(", "+seat_n, "");
                    Log.d("seatp Length2: ",seatp.length()+"");
                }else{
                    seatp= seatp.replace(seat_n+", ", "");
                    Log.d("Deleting: ",seat_n+"");
                    seatp = "";
                }*/
                Log.d("seatabzz: ",seatp);
                seatlabel.setText(seatp.trim());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Here the logic is good for 2nd or more items But didn't worked for the first item

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you well, you can use `ArrayList`
call `addOrRemoveItem()` on click at labels, passing the text you need to add
and when `save` or `next` or whatever is clicked call `getAsCommaSeparator()`

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

public void addOrRemoveItem(String item){
    if(items.contains(item)){
        items.remove(item);
    }else{
        items.add(item);
    }
}

public String getAsCommaSeparator(){
    return android.text.TextUtils.join(",",items);
}
```